# How To Tell If Applicant Was Granted a Patent

Tags: search, process

So if there is no patent, only a publication number how do I tell if they were ever granted a patent or if they were, where is it?  I'm looking at [publication # EP2526617](http://www.google.com/patents/EP2526617A1?cl=en).

Answer (score 3):

According to the EPO website, this patent application has been published and is pending examination.

https://register.epo.org/espacenet/application?number=EP11735182

Since it looks like priorty is claimed to a US filing, a search on the US Patent Office website seems to confirm that a US patent has not issued for this application.